# How to show all available commands in twitch stream chat?

Tags: twitch, twitch-api

Is there a universal way of seeing all available `!commands` that can be used in a streamer's chat? (via a command in the chat and/or the twitch API)

#### What I know so far

I know of `!commands` which gives a subset of the commands available for some streamers (but definitely not all available commands)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just entirely off topic.

Comment: @daniu i appreciate the feedback, rather than anonymous down/close vote. I guess you do not develop twitch extensions? The question is entirely on topic: it’s a coding question with a concrete desired outcome and an outline of what’s already been attempted.

Comment: I did retract my close vote because you're right, I cannot judge if it is entirely off topic. I guess if it's available via the API, it wouldn't be. Asking about what to enter in chat to get a list would be IMO.

Answer (score 0):

No becuase different streamers use different channel bots

And thus each channel bot will have different ways of presenting the channels commands, *if* all the commands are presented in a list for viewers at all.

Answer (score 0):

@BarryCarlyon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474297/how-to-show-all-available-commands-in-twitch-stream-chat/66479104#66479104) is correct. Commands are read and executed by third party addons (known as 'bots'), so how commands are interpreted differs depending on the bot(s) in use.

Some that can be tried are:

- Nightbot: `!commands`
- Streamlabs Chatbot (formerly Ankhbot): `!commands` or `!commandlist`
- MooBot: `!commands`.
- Streamelements: `!commands`

#### Notes

- The Twitch API can't help here (since the Twitch API doesn't know anything about what bot(s) the streamer is using, so it can't tell us anything about which commands those bots may use)
- Some streamers have a convention of having an `!info` command to give info about other available commands
- One last tip is to ask the streamer. Although that's not a programatic solution, it could be the most practical.